# How do I set a default calendar-app in Android (Jelly Bean)?

Tags: 4.1-jelly-bean, calendar, default-applications

I've installed PocketInformant and use it as my calendar app on my phone with Jelly Bean. However, when I get appointment/calendar event reminders, it's the stock calendar that notifies me. This is a bit annoying, since I sometimes wish to edit the appointment from within the reminder. Clicking edit brings up the stock calendar and not PocketInformant.

Is there a way to set PocketInformant as the default Calendar app? Or at least make it the default app for showing calendar reminders?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes!  you should be able to clear the stock app from being the default calendar app by following these steps:

- Go to the phone settings
- select apps
- scroll to the right two screen, to the 'All' section
- scroll down until you can find calendar, click on it
- scroll down the page and click the 'Clear defaults' button

Next time anything wants to use the calendar, you will be able to select which program you wish to use.

Comment: Thank you for your quick and thorough answer! However, the "Clear defaults" button for "Calendar" app is greyed out / passive. Any suggestions?

Comment: I just installed PocketInformant and it seems that they haven't setup the app in a way that you can enable it as a default calendar.  Your best bet is to email the company and ask for this feature

Comment: I should mention that I found this out by decompiling the source of the trial version of PocketInformant and checking the AndroidManifest file for the section which tells Android that it can be the default calendar app, which wasn't present

Comment: I am having a similar issue (greyed out "clear defaults" button) but I am trying to make it work with the google developed calendar app (rather than PocketInformant) and disable my samsung calendar app (which came on the device) as the default. Can't clear defaults on the samsung app, but it is the only one handling appointment files etc...